# How to get a specific tag attribute text in java with JSoup?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to get the url inside the  attribute , but each time I run my code I get an error.
Below is the snippet of the source url from where I want to extract the link :

```
  **<section class="rslwrp ">
  <div id="tab-5" class="tab-contentphone current">
  <ul class="rsl col-md-12 padding0">
  <input type="hidden" id="closedown_flag0" value="0">
  <li class="cntanr" data-href="https://www.somelink.com" >**
```

my code which I'm running

```
public class Wholelist {
static String url = "https://www.somewebsite.com"; 
static Document doc;
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    doc = getDoc(url);
    getlink(doc);
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
static Document getDoc(String url){
    try {
        return   Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("mozilla/17.0").validateTLSCertificates(false).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
    }
}
public static void getlink(Document doc1){
    Element elementlink = doc1.select("section.rslwrp").get(3).select("li.cntanr").get(5);
    String url = elementlink.attr("data-href"); 
    String Link = url;
    System.out.println(Link);
}
}
```

Please specify my mistake , and tell me the correct way to do so.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: What error you are getting, Can you specify exception.

Comment: I get the following Error while I run the code  **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
 at extract1.Wholelist.getlink(Wholelist.java:27)
 at extract1.Wholelist.main(Wholelist.java:15)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to get third nonexistent "section" element (having only one). That code will work with your data

```
Element elementlink = doc1.select("section.rslwrp").first().select("li.cntanr").first();
String url = elementlink.attr("data-href");
System.out.println(url);
```

And print the `https://www.somelink.com` as expected. Hope it helps!

**Edit after comments:**
If I understand you correctly, that will do the job.

```
List<String> urls = doc.select("section.rslwrp").first().select("li.cntanr")
        .stream().map(e -> e.attr("data-href")).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(urls);
```

Comment: Thanks .. It helped. But I have one more question that there are multiple links in the same page in the same format as above i.e. each link is inside separate ** <ul class="rsl col-md-12 padding0">
  <input type="hidden" id="closedown_flag0" value="0">
  <li class="cntanr" data-href="https://www.somelink.com" >**  . How to get all the links from the Page? Because when i ran the above code i just got link from one of the <li> tag.

Comment: @Maniraj, could you post entire snippet you want to parse, so I can help with it?

Comment: should i post the entire page source ?

Comment: @Maniraj, if you want... Or you can post just part from which you want to parse links, I need to see all of them and some enclosing tag.

Comment: sir , as the entire snippet is too long to post consider it in this way that there are multiple <li> tags inside <ul> tag in the same format as i gave for the one <li> tag and each <li> tag contains a link as shown in the above snippet. So i want to get all the links from each <li> tag, as by running the code i get only one of the link.

Comment: Can I get you're mail-id so that i can send you the entire snippet?

Comment: please give some respone as my problem is still not resolved.

Comment: @Maniraj, seprokof 'at' gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

Are there more sections rslwrp than 1 ? You are calling third element but there is just one element so you get index out of range exception :

```
    Element elementlink = doc1.select("section.rslwrp").get(3).select("li.cntanr").get(5);
```

Comment: Yes I got my mistake . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Element elementlink = doc1.select("section.rslwrp").get(3).select("li.cntanr").get(5);
```

In the above line first check selected elements are exist are not. If selected element are not empty only retrieve that.

```
Element elementlink = null;
Elements sectionElements = doc1.select("section.rslwrp");
if(!sectionElements.isEmpty() && elementlink.size() >= 3) {
    Elements liElements = elementlink.get(3).select("li.cntanr");
    if(!liElements.isEmpty() && liElements.size() >= 5) {
        elementlink = liElements.get(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using the select in a wrong way
You dont need to use two seperate selects and with the get() you are returning the wrong elements
To get the URL use

```
Element elementlink = doc1.select("li.cntanr").first();
String url = elementlink.attr("data-href"); 
String Link = url;
System.out.println(Link);
```

With this select your get you li element directly